# Custom user control not appearing in WPF window?

Tags: c#, wpf, user-controls

I have a custom WPF user control called a TimeoutPanel that I am trying to use. However, if I try to add it to my window from the .cs file, it does not actually show up.

I need to be able to get a handle to the window that owns the timeout screen.

```
TimeoutPanel tp = new TimeoutPanel(this);
tp.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
```

I would really appreciate it if someone could please point out what I am doing wrong!

Edit:
Here is the constructor for my TimeoutPanel

```
public TimeoutPanel(Window parent)
{
    this.InitializeComponent();
    parentWindow = parent;
}
```

I am calling it with the following code in the .cs file for a Homescreen window:

```
TimeoutPanel tp = new TimeoutPanel(this);
MainGrid.Children.Add(tp);
```

It crashes with exception:
Additional information: Cannot create object of type 'TicketBooth.TimeoutPanel'. CreateInstance failed, which can be caused by not having a public default constructor for 'TicketBooth.TimeoutPanel'.  Error at object 'System.Windows.Controls.Grid' in markup file 'TicketBooth;component/homescreen.xaml' Line 174 Position 10.

Thanks!

Comment: Ah, sorry I got it! The exception was a typo on my part... It appears to be working now! Thanks for all of your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are doing would in no way place that UserControl on the Window of your WPF application. You need to place the UserControl on a child within Window. Setting the Visiblity does not actually place the UserControl as a child of any container.

My guess is that a Grid is your container within the Window. If so; to add your UserControl to the Grid, simply add it as a child within the Grid. You will need to name your Grid prior to referencing it within the code behind...

```
TimeoutPanel tp = new TimeoutPanel(this);
myGrid.Children.Add(tp);
```

Answer (score 0):

you need to add this control to the some parent control collection.

Suppose , you have a stackpanel called stckPanel in your main window so if you want to show this created control under this stack panel , you need to do following code

```
TimeoutPanel tp = new TimeoutPanel(this);
stckPanel.Children.Add(tp);
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback! However, doing this it crashes. I have noticed however, that it works if I remove the parameter from the constructor (not really sure why it doesn't like the parameter). Perhaps the best approach is to just call a second method after setting it up to pass my parameter like:

TimeoutPanel tp = new TimeoutPanel();

tp.passPartent(this);

It would be great if you could explain why it crashes with a parameter though! Thanks!

Comment: @Kim Post the exception and what you are doing with that reference within the ctor

Comment: @Aaron Okay updated my original post so you could see. Thanks.